# Как получить в JS title сайта по ссылке?

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть много ссылок на разные сайты мне нужно получить title каждого сайта

Пример

Ссылка - https://www.imgonline.com.ua/resize-image-result.php

Мне нужно получить title этого сайта - "Результат обработки изображения - IMG online"

(title не моего документа, если кто-то не до конца понял)

Comment: Где вам нужно получить эти данные: изнутри вашей веб-странички, на вашем сервере или просто скриптом на локальном компьютеере?

Comment: пока локально только

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно получить такие данные локально, попробуйте освоить [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) — это библиотека для [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/), которая управляет скрытым браузером, в том числе чтобы собирать данные со страниц.

Например, если есть массив адресов, можно получить заголовки страниц по этим адресам таким небольшим скриптом:

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const urls = ['https://example.org/', 'https://example.com/', 'https://example.net/'];

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

try {
  const [page] = await browser.pages();

  const titles = [];

  for (const url of urls) {
    await page.goto(url);
    const title = await page.evaluate(() => document.title);
    titles.push(title);
  }

  console.log(titles); // [ 'Example Domain', 'Example Domain', 'Example Domain' ]
} catch (err) { console.error(err); } finally { await browser.close(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Рекомендую почитать к примеру вот эту статью https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch-crossorigin
2. Или сразу воспользоваться библиотекой "PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser", но это уже "php", а не JS.

Comment: Я только начал изучать JS и начинать еще PHP ну это сильно)